# How to debug ServiceStack integration tests on Visual Studio for Mac

Tags: debugging, asp.net-core, servicestack, integration-testing, visual-studio-mac

I have a (service) project that runs on ServiceStack on ASP.NET Core that has some integration tests for it.

The integration tests use a self hosted instance of the service to target. This uses `AppSelfHostBase` class to host the instance in the same process.

In the past I've done development on Windows and when the self hosted returned a HTTP 500 I could set Visual Studio to break on all exceptions and I could go and catch the exception, inspect the context, determine the fault and apply necessary fixes.

This strategy does not seem to work on OS X / Visual Studio for Mac because although I've set a breakpoint for all exceptions (I did it [like this](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/145778/#Comment_145778)) the "server" exception (i.e. the exception on the self hosted service thread) will not break (and further allow me to inspect etc.)

***How can I catch an exception on a self hosted ServiceStack service in Visual Studio for Mac?***

Is there some alternate way, such as subscribing to an event on the SelfHostBase or something else? Am I missing something obvious?

---

Later Edit: If it matters, I pulled a Windows machine, cloned the code and debugged and it's a missing dependency in the Funq IoC container. However this exception is not logged anywhere and, on OS X, I am not able to break the debugger when it happens.